# What does "all" in "It all started last night" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

> Dr. Jones is examining Alex. He has a bad stomachache.
>
> **Dr. Jones**: Good morning. What's the problem?
>   **Alex**: I have a terrible stomachache, doctor.
>   **Dr. Jones**: I see. When did it start?
>   **Alex**: It *all* started last night.

What part of speech is *all*: a pronoun, an adverb, or a determiner? And what does it mean in this context?

Comment: I would say it's an adjective, modifying "it" to let us know that "[Everything] started last night."

Comment: I take "it all" to be a compound pronoun: the two parts are inseparable, and function as subject of the sentence. The meaning can be glossed as "the problem in its entirety started last night".

Comment: It all started last night = Everything started last night.

Answer (score 0):

> It ***all*** started last night.

In here ***all*** is a *Quantificational Adjunct*. Reason?

- If we insert an auxiliary verb, like an adjunct it preferably follows the auxiliary verb.

> It *had* ***all*** started last night.

- we can replace *it* with any other Noun Phrase (NP).

> The pain all started last night.

**N.B-** This construction to be distinguished from the *they all, we both* etc. In OP's sentence *it all* is not a compound pronoun.

<sub>For more information please refer to The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language by Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey K. Pullum: page no. 427-428</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It simply means all things related to the subject under discussion. In this context it could mean that there are other symptoms related to the stomach ache, such as sickness.

This is a fairly common way of introducing relevant information, especially when someone wants to establish a particular starting point for a series of related events.